# Using a Doctrine package in an active record framework - Laravel

Tags: php, activerecord, laravel, doctrine-orm, sylius

Im struggling with certain decisions regarding the integration of Sylius Components into a Laravel e-commerce package ecosystem. As this would cut the development time massively and leverage a cross community solution. Issues with that im encountering are:

- Sylius is based off Doctrine ORM that uses the "data mapper" pattern. Unlike Laravel that uses Eloquent and an "active record" pattern
- We would risk alienating most of the Laravel community by using Doctrine. Thus loosing most of our user base and the project never really taking off?

**As I see it, if I ditch doctrine, and the data mapper pattern, for eloquent and an active record pattern, there is not much use for Sylius components apart from a little bit of a guide designing our own components on the active record pattern.**

**maybe there is another way that I could integrate sylius components, with their plain old PHP models that I'm just not seeing???**

Answer (score 1):

Many of Laravel Developers are looking for Doctrine as their options.
Few have switched from the some components of the Laravel like Blade to Twig.
My Point is there is upbeat demand of Laravel-Doctrine Package for Big Project to take on Laravel Framework.

I hope this will help!!!